# Colour gradients in Windows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having some trouble with my current R/RStudio setup. I am running R 3.1.1 and RStudio 0.98.1062 on a 64 bit Windows machine. I have version 1.0.0 of ggplot2 installed (although I got a warning during installation saying that it was compiled for R 3.1.2).

My problem is that colour gradients in legends do not render. Using the following example code (from the ggplot2 web site):

```
x.cell.boundary <- c(0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14)
example <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 2),
  y = factor(rep(c(1,2), each=5)),
  z = rep(1:5, each=2),
  w = rep(diff(x.cell.boundary), 2)
)

qplot(x, y, fill=z, data=example, geom="tile")
```

This produces the required heat map plot in the RStudio window but does not show the colour gradient in the legend (although the title and tic labels are present in the legend).

[image]

If I then plot

```
qplot(x, y, fill=factor(z), data=example, geom="tile", width=w)
```

then I do get a colour scale in the legend, but of course, this is a discrete colour scale. So this leads me to believe that the problem lies with colour **gradients**.

I have also found that if I save the resulting plot to either a jpg or png file then the colour scale gradient is absent. However, if I save it to a pdf file then the colour scale gradient does appear. This coupled with the previous observation suggests that the problem lies with rendering colour gradients but only on specific graphic devices.

I did find a thread alluding to a similar problem at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/BQxYYxTc5dE but no solution was provided.

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this issue? How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add resulting "problem" plot to your post. Is it different from http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html ? For me gradient works as in website, RStudio 0.98.1087, Win7, R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10), Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: I see the gradient with RStudio 0.98.1028, Win7, R 3.1.1.

Comment: Included plot showing the problem.

Comment: I also see the gradient as expected (RStudio 0.98.1056; Win 8 x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64; ggplot2 1.0.0; R 3.1.1).

Comment: Adter further exploration I have found that the colour gradient renders for png and svg files. It does not come out in any of jpg, tif, png, bmp or wmf. Is R using a different library to render scalable and bitmap images?